# Strange VS2013 Debugger Behavior with libpng 1.6.25

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, libpng

Using Visual Studio 2013, I'm encountering what seems like very bizarre behavior with the debugger, trying to step through some code that calls into libpng.  Here is some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <list>
#include "png.h"

int keypause(const char * message = 0) {
   if(message)
      std::cout << message << std::endl;
   return _getch();
}

struct chunk_t {
   png_bytep chunk_ptr;
   png_size_t length;
};
std::list<chunk_t> chunks;
std::stringstream flush_target;

void my_png_error_fn(png_structp png_ptr, png_const_charp message) {
   std::cout << "Well crap.  " << message << std::endl;
}

void my_png_write_fn(png_structrp png_ptr, png_bytep data, png_size_t length) {
   png_bytep chunk = new png_byte[length];
   memcpy(chunk, data, length);
   chunks.push_back({ chunk, length });
}

void my_png_read_fn(png_structrp png_ptr, png_bytep data, png_size_t length) {
}

void my_png_flush_fn(png_structp png_ptr) {
   for(auto chunk : chunks) {
      flush_target.write((const char *)chunk.chunk_ptr, chunk.length);
      delete[] chunk.chunk_ptr;
   }
   chunks.clear();
}

// ...

int main(void) {
   // ...

   png_structp png_ws_ptr = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, my_png_error_fn, my_png_error_fn);
   if(png_ws_ptr == nullptr) {
      keypause("png_ws_ptr is null");
      return 0;
   }

   png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ws_ptr);
   if(info_ptr == 0) {
      keypause("info_ptr is null");
      png_destroy_write_struct(&png_ws_ptr, (png_infopp)NULL);
      return 0;
   }
   if(setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ws_ptr))) {
      keypause("setjmp failed");
      png_destroy_write_struct(&png_ws_ptr, &info_ptr);
      return 0;
   }
   // ...
   png_set_write_fn(png_ws_ptr, NULL, my_png_write_fn, my_png_flush_fn);
   // ...
   png_write_png(png_ws_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);

   keypause("All done!");
   return 0;
}
```

The problem shows up when I try to set a breakpoint anywhere beyond the call to `png_create_write_struct`.  The IDE claims the breakpoint doesn't correspond to any compiled code in the target.  If I set a breakpoint prior to the call to `png_create_write_struct`, I can step into that function (I am linking with a debug build of libpng), all the way through it, and back out, and then the debugger gets lost.  It winds up thinking it's inside the `if(png_ws_ptr == nullptr) {` block, and if I continue clicking "Step Over", the current line of execution loops around and around inside that block.

What actually happens is that the program runs to the end of `main` and I see the message in the last call to `keypause`, waits for a keypress, and exits, but without actually doing any writing of PNG data.  I have breakpoints set in all of my callbacks and none of them gets hit.

Has anyone else run into such strange happenings?  Any suggestions on how to get the debugger to behave?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you debugging your project as a Release Build or as a Debug Build? I had breakpoints that got weird behavior on Release Builds

Comment: @FirstStep - Definitely a Debug build.  I've done the same thing enough times to check for that. ;-)

Comment: Cool then :) Just checking you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow.  Turns out the source file was corrupt with mismatched line-ending markers (CRLFs).  I didn't discover this until I closed and reopened the solution, and I was prompted to unify the line-endings.  A rebuild attempt then exposed a handful of syntax errors (which tells me the compiler wasn't compiling what I thought it was) which, when fixed, yielded a properly-debuggable executable.

It's the little things that can really get ya!